# Should a controller convert the data it extracts into the desired data type?

Tags: php, oop

Let's say we have a `Controllers\Cart` which has a method `postAdd()`. This method gets called when you send a POST request to `http://www.site.com/cart/add`. This is the controller method for adding a product to a shopping cart so obviously the `productId` will be posted.

Since all the POST data will come as a string when I do this in my controller

```
public function postAdd() {
    $productId = $this->request->post('productId'); // It is of a 'string' type.

    // You would then probably do something like...
    $this->shoppingService->addToCart($productId);

    .........
}
```

The interface for `Services\Shopping` would be

```
interface ShoppingInterface {

    /**
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function addToCart($productId);

}
```

Since PHP is loosely typed I can pass in a string to that method but should the data first be cast to an integer?

Comment: Impossible to say; depends on your addToCart -method, what is does...

Comment: But if the API says it needs type 'int' shouldn't I really give it data of that type? In Java or C++ you would not get away with passing a string in as a parameter when it expects an integer.

Comment: type cast to an int. (int) $this->request->post('productId'); you have no idea what the Post variable 'productId' contains.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have some sort of 'Form' class which implements any sort of validation tasks? Any incoming external data due to indeterminated nature should be validated.
Your example can be rewritten like this:

```
public function postAdd()
{
    $form = $this->getProductForm()
        ->import($this->request->post())
        ->checkRules();

    if ($form->getErrors()) {
        return new FormErrorResponse($form);
    }

    $this->shoppingService->addToCart($form->getValue('productId'));
    ...
}
```

Of course form validation can be extracted to private method (i.e. checkLoginForm). I don't see a reason for dedicating such small and easy readable lines to another class